# HTML5 Canvas avoid any subpixel rendering

Tags: javascript, rendering, antialiasing, html5-canvas

As seen [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017998/html-5-canvas-avoid-fill-behaviour-on-overlap) I have been having a few issues with sub pixel precision in the canvas. Now I'm having even more. I'm trying to render hard edged isometric squares as shown in the image in the link I provided. In an attempt to later work through the pixel data in the rendered image and extract the present colors.

[image: Sub Pixel]

But because of the sub pixel issue im having I'm receiving colors that aren't actually present in the original image! And no matter where i seem to start drawing the line you see in the image (whether it be at from [1,1] to [10,10] or [1.5, 1.5] to [10.5, 10.5], this is just an example) I am always getting these sub pixel colors that are ruining my results!

Does anyone know how I can avoid this or suggest the correct way I should draw a pseudo-isometric line (pseudo as in pixel art isometric angles) So I have nice hard edges on my shapes and I'm not ruining the rendered image with any sort of sub-pixel garbage.

Comment: Consider adding a tag for "antialiasing"?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well after some exhaustive research there seems to be no standardized way to stop what I'm experiencing.

Which is anti-aliasing that depending on the browser can only be enabled or disabled for certain drawing operations.

There are a few tricks on how to avoid anti-aliasing in some situations in this stack overflow question: [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element)

But the only one that will work for me is to manually implement my own drawing functions to produce the shapes I want without any anti-aliasing. This will be done with the canvas putImageData function and there is a good tutorial [right here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/pushing-pixels-with-canvas/) on ways of using this.

For the time being there is no api supported solution for the problem

Comment: This was the case in 2011, is it still the case in 2017?

Comment: @dom96 - As far as I can tell, it's still the case in 2024.  It's really sad how far we've regressed from being able to simply put a single pixel on screen. (And yes, Alvy Ray Smith, pixels _are_ squares.)

Comment: I'd just like to note, even if you draw your own lines using `putImageData`, the browser will randomly change pixel values in the red, green, and blue channels.  So you can't even  set all pixels to `#000` and do a simple flood fill.  Browser authors acknowledge this bug and yet the devs apparently refuse to fix it.  The situation is abysmal.